# Does ruid and suid and rgid and sgid have anything to do with permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, process

Each process has three user IDs:

- Real user ID (`ruid`).
- Effective user ID (`euid`).
- Saved user ID (`suid`).

Similarly, a process has three group IDs:

- Real group ID (`rgid`).
- Effective group ID (`egid`).
- Saved group ID (`sgid`).

Based on my understanding, the `euid` and `egid` (along with the `supplementary group IDs`) are used when dealing with permissions.

But what about the `ruid` and `suid` and `rgid` and `sgid`, do they play any role when dealing with permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Linux uses the filesystem user id and group id (plus of course the supplementary group ids) to determine permissions for accessing files; see [`setfsuid()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/setfsuid.2.html). Normally those are the same as the effective user ID and group ID. The real and saved user id and group id are never used for the purpose of determining access rights to files, shared memory etc.

The real and saved user id *are* used to determine whether a process can send a signal to another process; see [`man 2 kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/kill.2.html).

See [`man 7 credentials`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/credentials.7.html) for the complete discussion.

Comment: Is there a *filesystem supplementary group ids* also, or is there only `fsuid` and `fsgid`?

Comment: There is only one set of supplementary group ids, set by `setgroups()` and retrieved by `getgroups()`.